# UICollectionViewLayout - invalidateLayout() works only after screen rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewlayout

I subclassed `UICollectionViewLayout` in order to create a calendar. I would like to give users the ability to change some settings like the number of days to be shown on the screen (7 by default).
[image]

I save `daysToShow` in `UserDefaults`. Whenever the `UIStepper` value is changed it calls this method:

```
func stepperValueChanged(sender:UIStepper){
        stepperValue = String(Int(sender.value))
        valueLabel.text =  String(Int(sender.value))
        UserDefaults.standard.set(String(Int(sender.value)), forKey: "daysToShow")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "calendarSettingsChanged"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
 }
```

So after I save the new value in `UserDefault`, I post a notification which then calls `reloadForSettingsChange` (which is actually getting called as I set a breakpoint here):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reloadForSettingsChange(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "calendarSettingsChanged"), object: nil)

             // other code.....
}

func reloadForSettingsChange(notification:NSNotification){
        // here I save the user setting in a variable declared in my custom UICollectionViewLayout
        self.calendarView.daysToShow = Int(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "daysToShow")!)
        self.calendarView.daysToShowOnScreen  = Int(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "daysToShow")!)
        self.calendarView.forceReload(reloadEvent: true)

}

func forceReload(reloadEvent:Bool){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if reloadEvent{
            self.groupEventsByDays()
            self.weekFlowLayout?.invalidateCacheLayout()
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
func invalidateCacheLayout(){

    self.needsToPopulateAttributesForAllSections  = true
    self.cachedDayDateComponents?.removeAllObjects()
    self.cachedStartTimeDateComponents?.removeAllObjects()
    self.cachedEndTimeDateComponents?.removeAllObjects()
    self.cachedCurrentDateComponents?.removeAllObjects()
    self.cachedEarliestHour = Int.max
    self.cachedLatestHour = Int.min
    self.cachedMaxColumnHeight = CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
    self.cachedColumnHeights?.removeAllObjects()
    self.cachedEarliestHours?.removeAllObjects()
    self.cachedLatestHours?.removeAllObjects()
    self.itemAttributes?.removeAllObjects()
    self.allAttributes?.removeAllObjects()
    _layoutAttributes.removeAll()
    self.invalidateLayout()
}
```

The problem is that the layout is not being updated (invalidated?) until I rotate the screen device (i.e from landscape to portrait). The function I use for the rotation calls exactly the same method I call in `reloadForSettingsChange` so I don't understand why it works when I rotate the screen and not before:

```
 func rotated() {
        switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
        case .landscapeLeft, .landscapeRight:
            calendarView.forceReload(reloadEvent: true)
        default:
            calendarView.forceReload(reloadEvent: true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: I am now calling `setNeedsLayout()`:

```
func reloadForSettingsChange(notification:NSNotification){
        self.calendarView.daysToShow = Int(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "daysToShow")!)
        self.calendarView.daysToShowOnScreen  = Int(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "daysToShow")!)
        self.calendarView.forceReload(reloadEvent: true)
        self.calendarView.setNeedsLayout() // this line has been added 
}
```

I had initially used `layoutSubviews()` which worked but [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) says:

> You should not call this method directly. If you want to force a
>   layout update, call the setNeedsLayout() method instead to do so prior
>   to the next drawing update. If you want to update the layout of your
>   views immediately, call the layoutIfNeeded() method.

I tried `setNeedsLayout()` which seemed to be the right method to call (?!?) but since it wasn't working I used setNeedsLayout():

> Call this method on your application’s main thread when you want to
>   adjust the layout of a view’s subviews. This method makes a note of
>   the request and returns immediately. Because this method does not
>   force an immediate update, but instead waits for the next update
>   cycle, you can use it to invalidate the layout of multiple views
>   before any of those views are updated. This behavior allows you to
>   consolidate all of your layout updates to one update cycle, which is
>   usually better for performance.